# Explicitly validate Template Driven forms in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I have a template driven form which fills controls if data is available. But after the controls are filled, the error styles are not applied while validation(using Angular material elements). Error styles are applied only if I touch element or submit form. How can I trigger form validation manually ? 
You can check stackblitz: 
https://stackblitz.com/github/vugar005/Angular-NT-Components/tree/template-driven-approach 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please post an example. Most Angular form template examples only show the validation messages if the control has been touched or changed; your solution may be as simple as removing these conditions from the validation error message element but we will need an example.

Comment: added. please check .https://stackblitz.com/github/vugar005/Angular-NT-Components/tree/template-driven-approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trigger **markAsTouched()** method explicitly, if there is an error on input control during page load

```
getErrors(str) {
if (this.ntForm && this.ntForm.controls[str] ) {
  const control = this.ntForm.controls[str];
  const errors = control.errors; 
  if (!errors) { return; }      
  control.markAsTouched();
  // remaining code
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked ! I actually placed markAsTouched() after patching value of controls.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on exact requirements, you may want to just trigger validation on all form controls, there is a **markAllAsTouched()** method on the NgForm object that can do this:

```
forceValidation(form: NgForm) {
    if (!form.valid) {
        form.control.markAllAsTouched();
    }
}
```